# jQuery UI Touch Punch set left css?

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui

I want to use the jQuery Touch Punch plugin to do the following effect:

I have a Div which is only shown a little bit on the left side of my iPad screen. Now I want to use jQuery Touch Punch to pull it out. I can't seem to find how to restrain the properties, so I can write something like:

left-keyframe1: 0;
left-keyframe2: -48%;

I hope you get the idea. Also, when I pull out I want it to animate back when you didn't pull it out over 50%. Is there some documentation about this? I can't seem to find this. I looked through all examples on this site:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
$('.your-div').draggable(
        {
            scroll: false,
            start:function(){$startpos = $(this).position();$(this).css({'transition':'0','-webkit-transition':'0'});},
            stop:function(){
                $position = $(this).position();
                if($position.left > $startpos.left)
                {
                    $(this).animate({'left':'0'});
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).animate({'left':'-52%'});
                }
               $(this).css({'transition':'youramounts','-webkit-transition':'youramounts'});
            },
                axis:'x'
            });
```

Note: I added `transition:0`, because I had two eventtriggers and transition is conflicting with the dragfunction. The click and the drag. So on click I changed the css and did an animation via transition. If you do not have "transition" on your element, you don't need to include this.